# call javascript function outside of scope on ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a javascript library with a bunch of useful functions that I make use of across my website that does various things.

I know that I cannot access these functions from an ng-click, because the functions are outside of scope.

Is there a way to access them without having to declare a scope function that just makes a call to the function in the library?

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/aca320bt/) is a jsfiddle with an example. I would like to know if there's a way to make the second link work.
This is simply because I do not like the idea of defining a function that will simply call another function. e.g.

HTML:

```
<div ng-click="doSomething()">Click Me (Working)</div>
<div ng-click="doSomethingElse()">Click Me (Not Working)</div>
```

Controller JS:

```
$scope.doSomething = function () {
    doSomethingElse();
};
```

External Library JS:

```
function doSomethingElse() {
    alert("SomethingElse");
}
```

**<-------UPDATE------->**

Thanks for the creative responses guys!
Vinay K's answer is the easiest and most obvious, but I decided to go with Ron E's answer.
The reason is that I already have a global module with a collection of reusable directives and that would make it easier and cleaner to implement in my HTML. Also because I sometimes use more than one function from the library and then would have to chain them in the onclick:

```
onlick="func1(); func2(); func3();"
```

Where a directive is just cleaner and I can call as many functions as I like while doing other stuff as well.

Comment: No, you can't call non-$scope functions from the view, you can do `$scope.doSomething = doSomethingElse;`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a directive, here is an example:

```
// in your JS source
angular.directive('something', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function() {
                alert('yup');
            });
        }
    };
}]);

// in your HTML file
<button type="button" something>Click Me!</button>
```

This allows you to reuse your various code chunks / functions across your entire project pretty easily.

Answer (score 19):

`ng-click` expression (or any other expression in angular) will be evaluated in the context of the scope.

As `doSomethingElse` is not defined on scope it will not work.

Use `onclick` instead of `ng-click`

```
<div ng-click="doSomething()">Click Me</div>
<div onclick="doSomethingElse()">Click Me </div>
```

Comment: Doh!
Such an easy fix. It's obviously time to go to bed :P

Comment: I have the same issue using ng-class, although I use it in a table with together with ng-repeat, is it somehow possible to use standard class together with ng-repeat?

Answer (score 3):

Hi İf you have defined javascript function you can use old js functions and Angular js together

Example:

```
<div ng-click="doSomething()" class="myBtn"=>Click Me (Working)</div>
//JQuery Lib must be included your project
$(document).on('click','.btn',function(){
    eval($(this).attr('ng-click'));
});
function doSomething(){
//Bla Blo Blu Bli
}
```

Thank for reading

Comment: I like this eval thing. I gave a thumb up.
I wonder if the ng-click refers into a function in a scope, what I should do.

Answer (score 0):

If your library is available globally (for example, on the window object) you could write a method in your rootScope that accepts the function name as a parameter.  Guaranteed this isn't the most orthodox way to do things in Angular but it will eliminate the need to add all these extra methods in all of your scopes.  Here's a rough example:

In your app.run method you could add something like this:

```
$rootScope.callWindowMethod = function(methodName, parameter) {
  if(typeof window[methodName] !== 'function') {
    console.log('could not find ', methodName, ' function');
    return;
  }
  return window[methodName](parameter);
};
```

Then in your view you could do something like this:

```
<button ng-click="$root.callWindowMethod('alert','Hey there!')">Click Me</button>
```

You could get even fancier and pass in an arbitrary number of parameters to your function as well as have the function name contain dots for methods that are nested in other objects and split those up.  This should at least get you started.