# Angular ng-if take a global function

Tags: angularjs

i would like something like this in my angular markup for validation

```
<div ng-if="ShowError(LoginForm.password)">Invalid field</div>
```

then in my javascript a global function like this.

```
function ShowError(control){
    return control.$dirty && control.$invalid;
}
```

Comment: use directive instead of some global function.

Comment: You can have a look on this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28995714/call-javascript-function-outside-of-scope-on-ng-click   to use directive.